# .htaccess RewriteRule conditional rule

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to write a rule where the same link will point to the same page, except it will change the variable based on what follows "blog/" part of the URL. For example, if it's:

> mycooldomain.net/blog/new

It should redirect to

> mycooldomain.net/blog_page/index.php?do=new

I've tried the following but am not getting the desired results:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(^guest|new)?$ blog_page/index.php?do=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/?([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)?/?$ blog_page/index.php?article=$1 [NC,L]
```

On my index.php page I will add logic to load different page elements based on $_GET['do'].

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will do.

```
RewriteRule ^blog/new$ /blog_page/index.php?do=new [L,R=301]
```